# Set maximum Mount count of all ext3/4 filesystems to X

Tags: ansible

How can I set the maximum Mount count of all ext3/4 filesystems to `5` with Ansible?

I don't know the name of the devices before. This should just do this for all ext3/ext4 filesystems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you want to run `tune2fs` to set it up ? ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1241804))

You can loop over the mounts from `ansible_mounts`, for example

```
- name: do stuff
  shell: tune2fs blah
  when: item.fstype in ['ext3', 'ext4'] 
  loop: '{{ ansible_mounts }}'
```

Sample `ansible_mounts` entry (you can get this with `ansible all -i localhost, -c local -m setup`)

```
        "ansible_mounts": [
        {
            "device": "/dev/xvda1",
            "fstype": "ext4",
            "mount": "/",
            "options": "rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered",
            "size_available": 7028932608,
            "size_total": 8259014656,
            "uuid": "3b6570e3-e97a-4908-9dfe-0092c272ffdc"
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/loop0",
            "fstype": "squashfs",
            "mount": "/snap/core/6531",
            "options": "ro,nodev,relatime",
            "size_available": 0,
            "size_total": 95551488,
            "uuid": ""
        },
```

Comment: I am coming from a different config-management system. There you tried to only do things if necessary. I guess in this case this gets always executed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: ansible is 'ensuring state' so this will run all the time. If you want, you can create your own facts and query the max Mount count so ansible will set it up only if its required. https://medium.com/@jezhalford/ansible-custom-facts-1e1d1bf65db8

Comment: You write a link to a blog post. Where are the upstream docs (docs from ansible) for custom facts? I could only find blog post, I could not find official docs from ansible about this topic.

Comment: see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html, parameter `fact_path`. I dont think there is an official doc page about it.